# How to get Permissions for a SharePoint list item using graph SDK V5

Tags: permissions

We are using the request below in V4 to get the SharePoint list item permissions for both the document library and general list

```
        var graphClient = _factory.Create(tenantId);
        var request = graphClient
            .Sites[siteId]
            .Lists[listId]
            .Items[listItemUniqueId]
            .DriveItem
            .Permissions
            .Request()
            .WithMaxRetry(MsGraphPerformance.MaxRetry);

        var permissions = await request.GetAsync(cancellationToken);
```

After upgrading to V5, we can use two calls to get permissions for a document library item as below:

```
        var graphClient = _factory.Create(tenantId);

        var retryHandlerOption = new RetryHandlerOption
        {
            MaxRetry = MsGraphPerformance.MaxRetry,
        };

        var item = await graphClient
            .Sites[siteId]
            .Lists[listId]
            .Items[listItemUniqueId]
            .DriveItem
            .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.Options.Add(retryHandlerOption);
            }, cancellationToken);

        var permissions = await graphClient
            .Drives[item.ParentReference.DriveId]
            .Items[item.Id]
            .Permissions
            .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.Options.Add(retryHandlerOption);
            }, cancellationToken);
```

However, this method can't be used to get permissions for general list item.

Does anyone know how to get permission for a general list item using Graph SDK v5 client?

Try to get a general list item permission using Graph SDK V5 client